# Dual modules and bimodules for noncommutative rings

Tags: projective-module, finitely-generated, bimodules

Let $A$ be a noncommutative  (unital and associative) $\ast$-algebra over $\mathbb{C}$ and let $M$ be a left $A$-module. There is a left $A$-module structure on $$M'=\{f:M\longrightarrow A\mid f \mbox{ is a left }A\mbox{-module morphism} \}$$ given by $$(a,f)\longmapsto fa^{\ast}\;...\; (*)$$ where $$fa^{\ast}:M\longrightarrow A,\;\;\;\; m\longmapsto f(m)a^{\ast}$$ Also if  $M$ is an $A$-bimodule, we can define another $A$-bimodule structure on $M$ by means of 
\begin{equation*}
(a,m)  \longmapsto  m\, a^{\ast},
\qquad
(m,a) \longmapsto  a^{\ast} m 
\end{equation*}

We will denote by $M^*$ this new $A$-bimodule. My questions are

1) If $M$ is finitely generated and projective left $A$-module, is $M'$ (with (*)) finitely generated and projective left $A$-module too?

2) If $M$ is finitely generated and projective $A$-bimodule, is $M^*$ finitely generated and projective $A$-bimodule as well?.

In the second question, the part "finitely generated" is true but I am not so sure about the part "projective".